# Drop option in Python in not working for me

Tags: python, pandas

In my data set there is a column "Unnamed: 0". I have tried to drop using --- data.drop(['unnamed: 0'], axis=1, inplace=True) but it's not working. It's still showing the same: "Unnamed: 0".
And again whenever I am restarting the kernel the "Unnamed: 0" is getting dropped automatically. This is going off an on. Please suggest me what shall I do.

Comment: Did you try `data.drop(["Unnamed: 0"], axis=1, inplace=True)`? Notice I have used a capital "U" instead of "u". If not, print `data.columns` and copy the column name exactly. You might be missing leading or trailing whitespaces.

Comment: Does using `data.drop(columns=["Unnamed: 0"], axis=1, inplace=True)` help?

Comment: Can you show the code you’ve used?

Comment: Thank you for your help guys. It was solved